# Parse LiveQuery not working

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-server, livequery

I have a Parse server with a LiveQuery.

I can connect to the live query by the log info: `Create new client: 1`, and websocket.org confirms the connection, however none of the completion blocks are being called.

Here is the full code:

```
self.pfclient = [[PFLiveQueryClient alloc] init];
PFQuery* query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Reqs"];
[query whereKey:@"objectId" notEqualTo:@"asdfas"];
self.subscription = [self.pfclient subscribeToQuery:query];

[self.subscription addSubscribeHandler:^(PFQuery * _Nonnull query) {
    NSLog(@"Subscribed");
}];

[self.subscription addUpdateHandler:^(PFQuery * _Nonnull query, PFObject * _Nonnull obj) {
    NSLog(@"Update");
}];

[self.subscription addErrorHandler:^(PFQuery * _Nonnull query, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"Error");
}];
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3.0 Code that is working:

```
let liveQueryClient = ParseLiveQuery.Client(server: "...", applicationId: ..., clientKey: ..)
```

...

```
var subscription: Subscription<PFObject>?

let query: PFQuery<PFObject> = PFQuery(className: "className").whereKey("objectId", equalTo: "168sdf8438")

subscription = liveQueryClient.subscribe(query).handle(Event.created) { _, message in
            print("Object created")
    }
```

Comment: are you using pods ?

Comment: How do you integrate with swift 3 ? There are a lot of dependencies.

Comment: @AsadullahAli yes:
        pod 'ParseLiveQuery', git:     'https://github.com/parseplatform/ParseLiveQuery-iOS-OSX', branch: 'fix-object-decoding'

Comment: Wow I've been struggling for weeks. Thank you my man. I guess the old ParseLiveQuery seems to have issues connecting to AWS and Heroku.

Comment: When you write: `...` you mean to complete these params by ourselves?

Comment: @Etgar yes it's your server's credentials

Comment: @protspace So this is exactly what I did.
Still doesn't work... :(

Comment: @Etgar make sure that your server works properly with sockets

Comment: @protspace I think it is.
I can see the `Create new client: 1`
Your are more than welcome to take a look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44273455/parse-cloud-livequeries-ios-client-doesnt-work