# Parse Livequery changes not printing when there's an update

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

When I started working with parse live query I knew from the beginning it would be a challenge. Seeing that there were muiple ways to create a live query. When I had the set up the server early on, the bit of code I used to listen for updates looked like this:

```
let liveQueryClientMessage = ParseLiveQuery.Client()
    qMessages.whereKey("toUser", equalTo: (PFUser.current()?.objectId!)! as String)
    messageSubscription = liveQueryClientMessage.subscribe(qMessage).handle(Event.created){ _, message in
        //prepare a local notification alert
        print("object updated")
    }
```

This however, no longer seems to function properly. So I looked at the parse live query docs to see if there was a working example and found that this gets the server to "Create new client: " with this code:

```
let qMessages = PFQuery(className: "Messages")
    qMessages.whereKey("toUser", equalTo: (PFUser.current()?.objectId!)! as String)
    let subscription = Client.shared.subscribe(qMessages)
    subscription.handle(Event.updated){ query, event in
        print("object updated")
    }
```

But I am unable to get the print message to display... Am I missing something? I'm using the latest version of parselivequery I believe:

```
pod 'ParseLiveQuery'
```

UPDATE1: So I tried to rebuild the server and the issue still seems to persist. I'll try and make use of a parse query and see if its the filter...
UPDATE2: I rolled back the version of the podfile just in case it was an issue with just grabbing the lastest master branch. No fix yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to fixing this issue was related to where everything was defined. Refer to the awnser to this stackoverflow question: [Parse Cloud - LiveQueries - iOS Client doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44273455/parse-cloud-livequeries-ios-client-doesnt-work?rq=1) There's sufficient explanation there too.