# Parse Live Query: Not receiving Events on iOS Client. Our Parse server hosted on Azure App Services

Tags: ios, mongodb, azure, parse-platform, livequery

**Issue Description**

We have hosted Parse server on Azure App Services. We are able to connect to live Query and able to Subscribe to it. We are getting below messages.

2019-01-01 19:03:26.917094+0530 LiveQueryTest[59625:972922] ParseLiveQuery: Sending message:

```
{"clientKey":"xxxxxx","op":"connect","sessionToken":"","applicationId":"xxxxxx"}
2019-01-01 19:03:27.285251+0530 LiveQueryTest[59625:972922] ParseLiveQuery: Received message: {"op":"connected","clientId":5}
2019-01-01 19:03:27.388337+0530 LiveQueryTest[59625:972922] ParseLiveQuery: Sending message: {"query":{"className":"PostQuestionMessage","where":{"type":2}},"requestId":1,"op":"subscribe"}
2019-01-01 19:03:27.600455+0530 LiveQueryTest[59625:972813] ParseLiveQuery: Received message: {"op":"subscribed","clientId":5,"requestId":1}
```

And we are subscribed to Update Event but when we updated any records we are not getting event Back.

On the server:

We tried to listen to Specific port "1337" as below: Every time we do that our Parse Dashboard and API stops working. So Is it necessary to listen to specific port i.e "1337" or var port = process.env.PORT || 1337; will also work for Live Query.

```
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
var port = 1337;
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
console.log('Parse Server running at ${port}');
console.log("The value of port is " + port);
});
ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer);
```

**Expected Results**

We should get the event update as per our subscription.

**Actual Outcome**

Not receiving event updates as per the Query Subscribed,

**Environment Setup**

Server

parse-server version (Be specific! Don't say 'latest'.) : [2.3.8]

Operating System: [Linux]

[Remote Server - Azure]

Database

MongoDB version: [3.4]

[Remote Server - Azure]

**Logs/Trace**

Server:

[32minfo�[39m: Parse LiveQuery Server starts running

�[32minfo�[39m: Create new client: 1

**iOS client Code:**

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseLiveQuery

class LiveQueryManager {
    static let shared = LiveQueryManager()
    var liveQueryClient = ParseLiveQuery.Client()
    var subscription: Subscription<PostQuestionMessage>?
    var messagesQuery: PFQuery<PostQuestionMessage> {
        return (PostQuestionMessage.query()?
            .whereKey("type", equalTo: 2)) as! PFQuery<PostQuestionMessage>
    }
    init(){
        liveQueryClient.shouldPrintWebSocketLog = true
        liveQueryClient.shouldPrintWebSocketTrace = true
    }
    fileprivate func printMessage(_ message: PostQuestionMessage) {
        let createdAt = message.createdAt ?? Date()
        print("\(createdAt) : \(message.message ?? "")")
    }

    func subscribeToUpdates() {

        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44273455/parse-cloud-livequeries-ios-client-doesnt-work
        self.subscription = self.liveQueryClient.subscribe(messagesQuery)
        self.subscription = self.subscription?.handleEvent({ (_, event) in
            switch event {
            case .created(let object):
                print("Event Created")
                self.printMessage(object)
            // do stuff
            case .updated(let object):
                print("Event Updated")
                self.printMessage(object)

            default:
                break // do other stuff or do nothing
            }
        })

    }
    func disconnectFromSubscription() {
        if let objSubcription = self.subscription {
            self.liveQueryClient.unsubscribe(messagesQuery, handler: objSubcription)
        }

    }
    func printSubscription () {
        if let objSubscription = self.subscription {
            print ("Subscription:\(objSubscription)")
            print ("Client:\(self.liveQueryClient)")
            print ("Client userDisconnected:\(self.liveQueryClient.userDisconnected)")
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: ever solve this?